# Leaking hose connections for washing machine

Tags: plumbing

brand new washer G.E. when hook up hoses to inside hot and cold taps with included washers water sprays everywhere. The house is a log house therefore the taps are positioned at an angle not straight down. Not sure if this is an issue ? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check to see if the washers/seals are installed correctly?  Search online for an example of how these are installed correctly and inspect yours.  You shouldn't have to do much more than turn these fittings a couple of times with a pair of channel locks before it is tight.

Comment: How tight did you tighten the connections? Too loose is bad, but too tight can also be bad.

Comment: Ok will double check and did tighten exactly as per instructions. Hand tighten then 2/3 turn with wrench. Will try again and look online for washer placement. Thx